# Plotting on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a cobweb diagram using the following code:

```
function cobweb(f,a,b,x0,x1,N)
x(1)=0.2; % plot orbit starting at x0
for i=1:100
    x(i+1)= 3*x(i)*(1-x(i));
    plot([x(i),x(i)],[x(i),x(i+1)]);
    hold on
    plot([x(i),x(i+1)],[x(i+1),x(i+1)]);
    hold on
end

hold on
r = 3;
x = 0:0.01:1; %// set some x
f = (r.*x.*(1-x));
hold on
plot(x,f,'k')
hold on
plot([x(1), 0], [x(1), 3*x(1)*(1-x(1))])
```

I want the first line to be drawn up from the x-axis, however it's currently starting from (x(1),x(1)), where x(1) is the initial point.

I understand that this is because of my loop so I tried adding an extra plot for the initial line by plot([x(1), 0], [x(1), 3*x(1)*(1-x(1))]), however I still get the same result.

The function I am plotting is f = 3x(1-x).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move that line:

```
plot([x(1), 0], [x(1), 3*x(1)*(1-x(1))])
```

before the `for` loop and add a `hold on` after it before you enter the loop. You can then remove the other `hold on` inside the `for` loop and further down the code, as they are redundant.

Comment: I still get the same result!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question very well, but I have updated my answer. Hopefully this is what you want. If not, you probably need to clarify your question, it's not very clear right now.